# Ionic 2: Lazy load list's item value

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have list of items and want to load each item's one value through api call.

Problem: Api calling function(i.e getCount(value)) gets called infinite number of times.

This simple code illustrates my problem:

**Template file code:**

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">
    {{getCount(item.value) | async}}
  </ion-item>
```

**ts file code:**

```
export class LognPage {
  public items = [{ value: 1 }, { value: 2 }, { value: 3 }, { value: 4 }, { value: 5 }, { value: 6 }];

  getCount(value) {
    new Promise((reject, resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve("value " + value); // this is called infinite number of times
      }, 2000);
    });
  }
}
```

Does anyone provide any help?

What is reason of infinite calling, Can't I do like this way?

Answer (score 0):

don't use function in your templates :

```
valueList : Promise<any[]>

ngOnInit(){

  for(item of items){
    getCount(item ).then((value)=>{
       valueList.push(value);
   })
  }

}



getCount(value) {
    new Promise((reject, resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve("value " + value); // this is called infinite number of times
      }, 2000);
    });
  }
```

html :

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let value of valueList">
    {{value }}
  </ion-item>
```